# How to replace part of multi-line string with sed

Tags: sed

I want to replace newlines in a string with `<br/>` on all places not inside triple backticks statement(```)

String:

````
This is some requirements just talking about c++ with
`char` types supported by C++:
```
using SecureString = BasicSecureString<char>;
using WSecureString = BasicSecureString<wchar_t>;
using U16SecureString = BasicSecureString<char16_t>;
using U32SecureString = BasicSecureString<char32_t>;
```
And continuing to write
stuff
````

Expected result:

````
This is some requirements just talking about c++ with<br/>`char` types supported by C++:<br/>```
using SecureString = BasicSecureString<char>;
using WSecureString = BasicSecureString<wchar_t>;
using U16SecureString = BasicSecureString<char16_t>;
using U32SecureString = BasicSecureString<char32_t>;
```<br/>And continuing to write<br/>stuff
````

What I currently have is something like:

````
sed --null-data '/```.*```/!s/\n/<br\/>/g'
````

But it's only working on inputs which don't include the backticks.

Does someone have any hints?

Comment: when you use `-z`, you have only one *line*... `/regexp/!` applies to whole line, not part of the line

Comment: Yes that's what I thought as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `perl` or `awk`

````sh
perl -0777 -pe 's#```.*?```(*SKIP)(*F)|\n#<br/>#sg'

awk '/```/{f=!f} {ORS = f ? RS : "<br/>"} 1'
````

The `perl` solution is similar to what you tried with `sed`.

- `-0777` will slurp entire input file, similar to `sed -z` but `-z` works by using ASCII NUL as line separator
- ```` ```.*?```(*SKIP)(*F) ```` to prevent this matching portion from being changed
- `|\n` specified what should be matched
- `<br/>` replacement string
- `s` flag to allow `.` to match newline characters as well

With `awk`, the output record separator is changed based on value of `f` which changes whenever input has triple backticks. The advantage with this approach is that whole input doesn't have to be slurped.

If you don't wish to change the last newline in the file, use

````sh
perl -0777 -pe 's#```.*?```(*SKIP)(*F)|\n(?!\z)#<br/>#sg'
````